# How to use DM (direct message) correctly

Tags: american-english, british-english

How to write correctly 'send your request to DM (direct message) or in DM or perhaps via DM?'

Comment: It depends on how "DM" is understood.  It's not that familiar to me.

Comment: it is used in social media, on instagram for example when you send a message to another person privatly. I just don't know which preposition to use with it.

Comment: "DM your request"

Comment: Since "DM" is not a part of Standard English, there is no "correct" answer.

Comment: Would you have the same trouble with "How to write correctly 'send your request to a letter or in a letter or perhaps via a letter' "?

How would it wrong to ask "How to write correctly 'send your request to TXT or in TXT or perhaps via TXT' "?

If those are equally difficult, why would they not be better served at English Language Learners?

Comment: The first version means something completely different from the other two versions. *Send your request **to** DM* means *send your (desire) to (participate in a DM) (to someone).* Or, in other words, *I would like to DM.* That's not at all the same as *send a request of an unspecified nature by using a DM as the medium of the request.*

Answer (score 1):

**DM** stands for **Direct Message**. It is used on social media sites and services, such as Facebook, Twitter, Instagram or Discord. You could also say *PM (Private Message)*. In social media sites, there are often groups/ servers in which there are loads of people and if you want to send someone a private message (so other people do not see it), you tell them to check their DM's (Direct Messages).
It is a private form of communication between social media users that is only visible to the sender and recipient (or recipients. depends on who you add to DM's).
It is a noun.

**For example:** Send the files by direct message (or DM). (DM is used as a noun)

However, in informal situations, the abbreviated form (i.e. DM) is also used as a verb.

**For example:** DM the details to me.